# How to implement onCompletion listener for the following code

Tags: android, listview, audio

Playing audio files from sd card by placing in a listview here how to play all songs in this list continuously,by using onCompletion listener we can do it ,followed developer page didn't get it ,could you plz suggest me how to implement onCompletion listener based on this code

```
    package sample.music;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class MusicActivity extends Activity {
      ListView musiclist;
      Cursor musiccursor;
      int music_column_index;
      int count;
      MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

      /** Called when the activity is first created. */
      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            init_phone_music_grid();
      }

      private void init_phone_music_grid() {
            System.gc();
            String[] proj = { MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE };
            musiccursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
proj, null, null, null);
            count = musiccursor.getCount();
            musiclist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.PhoneMusicList);
            musiclist.setAdapter(new MusicAdapter(getApplicationContext()));

            musiclist.setOnItemClickListener(musicgridlistener);
            mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
      }

      private OnItemClickListener musicgridlistener = new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position,
long id) {
                  System.gc();
                  music_column_index = musiccursor
.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
                  musiccursor.moveToPosition(position);
                  String filename = musiccursor.getString(music_column_index);

                  try {
                        if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                              mMediaPlayer.reset();
                        }
                        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(filename);
                        mMediaPlayer.prepare();
                        mMediaPlayer.start();
                  } catch (Exception e) {

                  }
            }
      };

      public class MusicAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
            private Context mContext;

            public MusicAdapter(Context c) {
                  mContext = c;
            }

            public int getCount() {
                  return count;
            }

            public Object getItem(int position) {
                  return position;
            }

            public long getItemId(int position) {
                  return position;
            }

            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                  System.gc();
                  TextView tv = new TextView(mContext.getApplicationContext());
                  String id = null;
                  if (convertView == null) {
                        music_column_index = musiccursor
.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
                        musiccursor.moveToPosition(position);
                        id = musiccursor.getString(music_column_index);
                        music_column_index = musiccursor
.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE);
                        musiccursor.moveToPosition(position);
                        id += " Size(KB):" + musiccursor.getString(music_column_index);
                        tv.setText(id);
                  } else
                        tv = (TextView) convertView;
                  return tv;
            }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                //put your code here.....

            }
        });
```

after initializing mediaplayer ,you can add on completion listener .
otherwise you can use this code:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,Uri.parse("android.resource://emad.app/raw/seven_chimes"));

mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                performOnEnd();
            }

            });

    mp.start();
```